# Resize Jquery Datepicker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

How can I resize the datepicker?

Do help me. The size is too big.. Is it possible to resize it in Jquery?

Here's my code:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function() {
            $("#datepicker").datepicker();
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <p>Date:
        <input type="text" id="datepicker">
    </p>
</body>
```

Comment: you may need to edit `jquery ui` css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, add this with your css file,
This will change the control size

```
div.ui-datepicker{font-size:10px;}
```

also try this

```
$('div.ui-datepicker').css({ font-size:10px; });
```